# How to fake a package version installed?

Tags: apt, dpkg

Being an early adopter and using 11.04 daily builds I sometimes meet a situation when some packages require earlier versions of other packages than those I have installed. Usually newer (but refused) versions of needed packages provide all the functionality of their older versions.

If I use `dpkg -i --force-depends-version` to install dependent packages everything works fine, I've never seen a problem.

Instead of manually downloading and installing every package, can I just make the system pretend there is a specific package version installed when there is a newer? Or is there a `--force-depends-version` key equivalent for `apt-get`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the `equivs` package to create a dummy package to fake a given package being installed. Some instructions [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20161231151951/http://eric.lubow.org/2010/system-administration/creating-dummy-packages-on-debian/).

Comment: While this is enough. But the link may break sooner or later. Better to have  at least resumed instruction within the answer. My answer may help here https://askubuntu.com/a/1181415/26246 . So we can reference this question which have the higher vote concerning equivs.

Answer (score 40):

Despite an answer being already accepted, inlining the accepted better conveys the process:

1. There is a Debian package called `equivs` that is able to create dummy packages.  Install it by running `sudo apt-get install -y equivs`
2. Once installed, you generate a template "control" file using the following command: `equivs-control postfix` (replace `postfix` with your package name). In my case, I might use an alternate package name, e.g. `postfix-custom` or whatever but have my custom package fulfill or `Provides` the installation dependency of `postfix` (again replacing `postfix` for whatever package you want.
3. Once the template control file is generated, I will typically remove a lot of the commented out statements (statements that begin with `#`). One that I like to keep specifically is the `Provides:` statement where I can say that my package provides the capability offered by the other package that I'm trying to fake, e.g. `Provides: postfix` tells the Debian/Ubuntu dependency resolution mechanism that my package—of whatever name—provides the same capabilities of the target package, again `postfix` or whatever. This allows me to name my package independently of the target package to avoid confusion. Erlang Factory does this with their stuff, e.g. `esl-erlang` provides `erlang`.
4. Finally, once the template control file is created, you use `equivs-build` to generate the fake package, e.g. `equivs-build /path/to/generated/control/file`.
5. It takes a few seconds to build the package and then you can run `sudo dpkg -i my_package_name*.deb`

For advanced users, if your template control file has a `Requires:` dependency line, you may want to use a tool like `gdebi` to install your package as well as the various the packages it declares as dependencies.