# When creating a deb package, can I have it depend on a file instead of on a package

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies

I'm building a deb file to deploy to a machine that may have a dependency satisfied by a non-deb deployment. I want to have my package depend on the existence of a file rather than a specific (or virtual) package, so that if the file was deployed using a method other than apt-get, the package can still be installed.

I know that RPM has a mechanism for that, but I couldn't figure out how to do this with dpkg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no such mechanism for Debian packages. Users of Debian-based systems have to work around this, there's nothing the package maintainer can do. See [How to fake a package version installed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18192/how-to-fake-a-package-version-installed) - also `checkinstall` can be used by the user to fill the package database.