# how to install a specific package version

Tags: apt, package-management, python, dpkg

I'm building my first debian package (django), which needs some dependencies, so I was wondering if it's possible to install a specific package version with `apt-get`.

For example instead of

`pip install gunicorn==19.3.0`

`apt-get install gunicorn==19.3.0`

(which obviously doesn't work, only `apt-get install gunicorn` works, however then it will install the latest version)

Ultimately, this is supposed into the `Depends` section of the `control` file.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can also use dpkg to install any downloaded version or see here on how to fake a version http://askubuntu.com/questions/18192/how-to-fake-a-package-version-installed

Comment: 19.3 does not seem to be available through apt-get unless you have a ppa which provides this version.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Execute

```
man apt-get
```

and go down (/) to the **install** function.  This is worth reading.

By the way, did you try the following?

```
sudo apt-get install gunicorn=19.3.0
```

(one equal sign, not two)

As the man page states, use this feature with care.  I don't know why you'd want an older version of a package on your installation but I'd guess that it would be a lot easier in the long run to change the dependent package to rely on the latest version of a dependency (gunicorn?) and not keep using an older version.  Cleaner, IMO.