# Does ubuntu's installation of mysql-server-5.7 now require apparmor?

Tags: server, apt, mysql

Ubuntu 16.04: When I use apt to install mysql, it shows:

```
The following additional packages will be installed:
  apparmor mysql-server-5.7
Suggested packages:
  apparmor-profiles apparmor-profiles-extra apparmor-docs apparmor-utils tinyca
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apparmor mysql-server mysql-server-5.7
```

Further, when  I uninstall app-armor, it shows:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  apparmor mysql-server mysql-server-5.7
```

Am I missing something here? I simply want to install mysql and avoid the third (apparmor) and fourth (SElinux) planes of Hell.

Comment: ever figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

The MySQL packages on Ubuntu have had included [an AppArmor profile since 14.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty-updates/amd64/mysql-server-5.5/filelist), and if the packages didn't depend on AppArmor, then it must have been an oversight or reliance on some indirect dependency. In any case, the changelog for the MySQL packages says:

```
mysql-5.7 (5.7.11-0ubuntu3) xenial; urgency=medium

  * Ubuntu upload from Debian VCS c17404a.
  * FFe update to MySQL 5.7 (LP: #1528583).
  * Revert "Build with libmecab-dev" since libmecab-dev is in universe.
  * mysql-server-5.7: depend on apparmor (>= 2.10) for Trusty upgrade
    path.

 -- Robie Basak <robie.basak@ubuntu.com>  Wed, 16 Mar 2016 14:01:31 +0000
```

So, yes, it does require AppArmor. If you really want to avoid AppArmor, you'd have to rebuild the package to remove the dependency, or [fake the dependency.](https://askubuntu.com/q/18192/158442)