# Cannot uninstall imagemagick

Tags: apt, package-management, uninstall

I just want to uninstall `imagemagick` from Ubuntu 16.04.
When I run `sudo apt remove imagemagick` I get this output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
fonts-jsmath gnuplot-data gnuplot-tex gnuplot-x11 liblua5.1-0 maxima maxima-doc maxima-share
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
foomatic-filters libpaps0 paps
The following packages will be REMOVED:
bluez-cups cups cups-filters hplip imagemagick indicator-printers printer-driver-gutenprint printer-driver-hpcups printer-driver-postscript-hp
printer-driver-pxljr printer-driver-splix wxmaxima
The following NEW packages will be installed:
foomatic-filters libpaps0 paps
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 12 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 111 kB of archives.
After this operation, 14.2 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
Abort.
```

Why it want to uninstall `cups` and `wxmaxima`? I thought imagemagick is simple graphics editor but it has strange dependencies. Can I remove `imagemagick` without removing `wxmaxima`, `cups`, etc.?

Comment: Please use `sudo env LC_ALL=C apt remove imagemagick` so we can get English output.

Comment: @muru I've made english output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`cups`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/cups) depends on `cups-filters` and [`cups-filters`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/cups-filters) depends on `imagemagick`. The only way you can remove `imagemagick` is if you install [`graphicsmagick-imagemagick-compat`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/graphicsmagick-imagemagick-compat) (which will involve installing `graphicsmagick`). [`wxmaxima`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/wxmaxima) also depends on `imagemagick`. You can try: [How to fake a package version installed?](https://askubuntu.com/q/18192/158442), though who knows what might break if you do that.

Answer (score 2):

Before removing it,you should know that you will also remove `cups` (which is parts of the printing system).

`cups` uses `imagemagick` for its filters and while it's possible that you don't use any filters that use ImageMagick, I'd recommend that you keep it.

So it's bad idea to remove `imagemagick`, because removing it may break your printing system.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
sudo su
apt autoremove --purge imagemagick
apt autoremove --purge imagemagick-6.q16
apt autoremove --purge imagemagick-6-common
```

Comment: This answer appears to be far less useful than the previous ones that actually addressed the risks involved in taking this course of action.