# Problem booting Ubuntu 16.04: Plymouth crashes, blinking screen after grub

Tags: boot, 16.04, dual-boot, plymouth

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 alongside Windows 7 without prior experience on Linux. It worked fine until after a few reboots after I started installing applications including Chromium and some tweak tools like ccsm. For what it's worth I also uninstalled a few unnecessary softwares. Now Ubuntu fails to proceed beyond grub. I am getting screens that are either like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJKlc.jpg) (ignore LCD stains) or [a blinking Ubuntu logo overlayed with a blinking boot log which says `FAILED` or `DEPENDS` next to PLYMOUTH and/or LSB:AppArmor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fi4Ic.jpg). Whenever I manage to get to the login screen for some reason, a window would pop up telling me that an internal error has occurred and plymouth has crashed.

Aside from repeatedly powering-on and -off until I make it to the login screen, I have tried transferring ownership of `/var/lib/plymouth` to my username, but that didn't help. As a novice user, I find this frustrating as I don't really want to revert back to Windows.

Also, when I first booted from a live usb, I can recall already seeing from the scrolling bootlog the word `FAILED` followed by *Plymouth*.

Anyone have a hint on what's causing this problem? How can I get around it? I would very much appreciate if someone can explain things a bit explicitly, as I said I don't have much experience on Linux.

Comment: What "unnecessary softwares" did you remove?

Comment: @Organic Marble, things like  imagemagick, games and thunderbird. I also replaced firefox with chromium.

Comment: Imagemagick is an important system component. Removing it is a good way to break your system.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/839890/cannot-uninstall-imagemagick

Comment: Noted. But as I said there was already a problem with plymouth even before the OS was installed.