# Replacing 16.04 with 14.04

Tags: boot, 16.04, dual-boot, plymouth

I have a Win7-Ubuntu16.04 dual-boot non-UEFI laptop. I'm planning to downgrade my Ubuntu to 14.04 LTS after having a [problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/915813/problem-booting-ubuntu-16-04-plymouth-crashes-blinking-screen-after-grub) with 16.04 not booting properly. I don't have important files in the Ubuntu partition to worry about so I'm thinking of outright deleting it with the Windows Disk Manager, and afterwards boot to a live 14.04 disk and install from there.

On top of this, I'm not planning on restoring the Windows boot loader (since I can't, anyway. CD drive broken). So unless 14.04 installs correctly or at least a new grub is put in place, then probably goodbye Windows as well.

**I just want to know if what I'm about to do is perfectly, definitely OK.** What are the odds of 14.04 not installing successfully or booting in the first place? I'm using Rufus to burn the ISO into a USB drive.

Comment: Why do you think 14.04 will work if 16.04 doesn't? If you're using newer hardware, the reverse is much more likely

Comment: I'm using a 10-year old computer with Vista originally installed on it. I don't know maybe my frustration with 16.04 is clouding my reasoning. Perhaps I'm going to try another distro sometime. But for now I just want to have a working Linux machine

Answer (score 1):

Why delete it with the Windows disk manager? You can make all your alterations with the live usb-stick's volume manager, after booting with the live usb-drive. You can even leave Windows in place then, if you like.

Just boot with the live usb-stick. See if it works, replace Ubuntu with the old one, see if it boots.

If GRUB for some reason doesn't work then, you can use the live usb-stick to boot from either the stick, the Ubuntu partition or the Windows partition.