# How to fake resolve a dependency in apt-get?

Tags: 14.04, apt

How can I trick `apt-get` to believe that a dependency of an about to be installed package is already installed, so that the referencing package can be installed without installing the dependency ?
Do I have to edit `/var/lib/dpkg/status` ?

In my real-world case I want to install `nagios` without having to install `mailx` and `postfix`.
I made a shell script `/usr/local/bin/mailx` that uses `msmtp` to send mail remotely and linked that to `/usr/bin/mailx` using `update-alternatives`.
So I don't need and don't want a local mail infrastructure installed, but `nagios3-common` depends on `bsd-mailx | mailx`.

`apt-get --force-yes install nagios3-common` does not help, neither does defining a negative priority for `*mail*` packages in `/etc/apt/preferences`.

Comment: Easiest is to unpack the .deb, modify the control file, i.e. remove the dependency in question. Then repack & install the redone .deb. I've a script that makes the task quite simple if you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for my real-world case:

```
apt-get install --no-install-recommends equivs
echo -e 'Package: mailx-dummy\nProvides: mail, mailx\nDescription: fake mail/mailx' > mailx-dummy.ctl
equivs-build mailx-dummy.ctl && dpkg -i mailx-dummy*.deb
apt-get install --no-install-recommends nagios3
```

Yes, this is a duplicate of [How to fake a package version installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18192/how-to-fake-a-package-version-installed).
Did not mark this question as a duplicate because this is a specific four-line-solution for installing `nagios` without `mailx` and `postfix` and might be helpful besides the original question.