# tls-remote workaround for openvpn on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.10, openvpn, downgrade

I try to work around that the option

```
--tls-remote
```

was removed in openvpn 2.4 so my openvpn config file does not work any more.

I tried to downgrade openvpn from 2.4 in Ubuntu 17.10 down to 2.3.4:

```
apt remove openvpn
wget http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/o/openvpn/openvpn_2.3.4-5+deb8u2_amd64.deb
dpkg -i openvpn_2.3.4-5+deb8u2_amd64.deb
```

But it seems like 2.3 is not compatible with Ubuntu 17.10: it sais, missing package `initscripts` which is not installable on 17.10.

What can I do to get my old config running? Or can I change the config, so it works with 2.4? This is the offending line:

```
tls-remote "/C=de/L=SomeTown/O=Something/CN=asg.myserver.de/emailAddress=administrator@myserver.de"
```

Comment: ... rebuild the old
 package from source, but remove the dependency, or fake the dependency: https://askubuntu.com/q/18192/158442

Comment: The option was probably removed for a reason; update your configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to replace the `--tls-remote name` with the new `--verify-x509-name name type` directive:

https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/DeprecatedOptions#a--tls-remote

So instead of the tls-remote command use this:

```
verify-x509-name 'C=de, L=SomeTown, O=Something, CN=asg.myserver.de, emailAddress=administrator@myserver.de'
```

strangely , this didnt work on my system, I got an error:

```
VERIFY X509NAME ERROR: C=de, L=SomeTown, O=Something, CN=asg.myserver.de, emailAddress=administrator@myserver.de, must be C=de, L=SomeTown, O=Something, CN=asg.myserver.de, emailAddress=administrator@myserver.de
```

Which seems a really strange message, so I tried around some more options and found out, it works with the type `name` instead of the (default) type `subject`:

```
verify-x509-name asg.myserver.de name
```

Answer (score 3):

The new configuration option to use is `verify-x509-name` it appears to expect a comma and space separated list for your Distinguished Name (DN):

```
verify-x509-name 'C=de, L=SomeTown, O=Something, CN=asg.myserver.de, emailAddress=administrator@myserver.de'
```

This information is from the [OpenVPN man page for 2.4](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn24ManPage), in the TLS Mode Options section. The example there only uses the C, ST, L and CN parts to make up the DN, but it looks like it should work with other DN components