# How to install qtbase-abi-5-9-5 in Ubuntu 19.10?

Tags: 19.10

How can I install the package `qtbase-abi-5-9-5` in Ubuntu 19.10? I cannot find this package in the package search.

I need this to allow the installation of this government application from https://www.autenticacao.gov.pt/cc-software:
https://www.autenticacao.gov.pt/documents/10179/11962/Autenticacao.gov_Ubuntu_18_x64.deb

It was made for Ubuntu 18 but it only requires the qtbase to run.

**UPDATE 1:**
Did not work. I already have installed the libqt5core5a but keeps asking for the qtbase-abi-5-9-5:

```
libqt5core5a is already the newest version (5.12.4+dfsg-4ubuntu1.1)
```

Comment: You best ask the providers of that software for an updated version - **or** you install 18.04 in a virtual machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`qtbase-abi-5-9-5` is a [virtual package](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-binary.html#virtual-packages) used only in Ubuntu 18.04, it references [the `libqt5core5a` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libqt5core5a) (see [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/en/bionic/qtbase-abi-5-9-5)) which is available in all currently supported releases, including 19.10:

```
sudo apt install libqt5core5a
```

<sub>Note that I was not able to find that with the search function on packages.ubuntu.com itself, but used [a startpage search](https://www.startpage.com/rvd/search?query=qtbase-abi-5-9-5&language=en) instead.</sub>

If the program tests for a package called `qtbase-abi-5-9-5` instead of the qt5 library from the above package I’d just fake the package with `equivs`, see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/656153/507051) and the steps [here](https://eric.lubow.org/2010/creating-dummy-packages-on-debian/).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the same app, so do the following.

1. Download the .deb package
2. Install dependencies `sudo apt install libcurl3-nss libnsspem libxerces-c3.2 libxml-security-c20 binutils`
3. Uncompress the deb file using binutils: `ar -x $YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME$.deb`
4. Uncompress the control file: `tar xf control.tar.xz`
5. Edit the control file and remove unwanted dependencies or in this case `sed -i 's|, qtbase-abi-5-12-4||g' control`
6. Recompress the content file : `tar cfJ control.tar.xz control md5sums postinst postrm`
7. Remove the uncompressed files `rm control md5sums postinst postrm`
8. Rebuild the .deb file : `ar rcs $NEW_PACKAGE_NAME$.deb debian-binary control.tar.xz data.tar.xz`
9. Install it with: `sudo dpkg -i $NEW_PACKAGE_NAME$.deb`

Answer (score 0):

New download versions were recently published for 18.04, 19.10 and 20.04:

https://www.autenticacao.gov.pt/cc-aplicacao