What happened to openresolv on Ubuntu 24.04? "Package 'openresolv' has no installation candidate" What is it's replacement, or how do I get it?
It seems Ubuntu 24.04 Server no longer has the Openresolv package. I need it, or an alternative that does the same thing. I get a "E: Package 'openresolv' has no installation candidate" when trying to do an apt install.
sudo apt install openresolv
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package openresolv is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'openresolv' has no installation candidate

How do I get openresolv on Ubuntu 24.04, and if I can't, what can I download as a replacement?

According to the publishing history was removed in Ubuntu 23.10, because it:

Conflicts with systemd-resolved, which is now the preferred implementation as of kinetic; LP: #1990743

And from that bug report:

Upon further inspection, it turns out that systemd-resolved now implements the resolvconf interface. We should drop resolvconf and openresolv now from the archive, and users requesting resolvconf will be directed to systemd-resolved. Packages which depend/recommend systemd-resolved will also get the supported implementation going forward.

So systemd-resolved (which should be pre-installed) is what you should use.

how to force install openresolv?

To what purpose?

This binary is depending on openresolv: https://gitlab.com/fscarmen/warp

That repo seems to be reasonably active, you should ask them to create a release with openresolv optional. Or you can use equivs to make a dummy package to satisfy  dependencies: https://askubuntu.com/q/18192/158442
